# facing error when trying to generate schema from jaxb classes in eclipse

Tags: jaxb

I am facing the below error when I am trying to generate schema from jaxb classes in eclipse.
From the below error, am able to understand that issue is with one of the annotation annotated in jaxb classes.

But from below error, it is difficult to find the which annotation from which jaxb class is causing error.

Can anybody suggest how to debug this issue.

### Error:

!loading...!

```
!com.XX.XXX.utils.Pageable!

 !com.XX.XX.utils.MetaData!

 !com.xx.xxx.utils.Page!
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayStoreException:      sun.reflect.annotation.EnumConstantNotPresentExceptionProxy
at     sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseEnumArray(AnnotationParser.java:744)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(AnnotationParser.java:533)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:355)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(AnnotationParser.java:286)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:120)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:72)
at java.lang.reflect.Field.declaredAnnotations(Field.java:1150)
at java.lang.reflect.Field.declaredAnnotations(Field.java:1148)
at java.lang.reflect.Field.getDeclaredAnnotations(Field.java:1139)
at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.getAnnotations(AccessibleObject.java:207)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.annotation.RuntimeInlineAnnotationReader.getAllFieldAnnotations(RuntimeInlineAnnotationReader.java:73)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.annotation.RuntimeInlineAnnotationReader.getAllFieldAnnotations(RuntimeInlineAnnotationReader.java:57)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ClassInfoImpl.findFieldProperties(ClassInfoImpl.java:381)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ClassInfoImpl.getProperties(ClassInfoImpl.java:311)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeClassInfoImpl.getProperties(RuntimeClassInfoImpl.java:186)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:261)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:104)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:85)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:227)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:99)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:85)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:375)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.TypeRefImpl.calcRef(TypeRefImpl.java:96)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.TypeRefImpl.getTarget(TypeRefImpl.java:73)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeTypeRefImpl.getTarget(RuntimeTypeRefImpl.java:62)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeTypeRefImpl.getTarget(RuntimeTypeRefImpl.java:55)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ElementPropertyInfoImpl$1.get(ElementPropertyInfoImpl.java:78)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ElementPropertyInfoImpl$1.get(ElementPropertyInfoImpl.java:76)
at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(AbstractList.java:358)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:275)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:104)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:85)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:227)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:99)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:85)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:375)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:290)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:104)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:85)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:227)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:99)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:85)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:375)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:390)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:465)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:303)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:142)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1174)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:162)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:247)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:234)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:441)
at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:641)
at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:584)
at org.eclipse.jpt.jaxb.core.schemagen.Main.buildJaxbContext(Main.java:99)
at org.eclipse.jpt.jaxb.core.schemagen.Main.generate(Main.java:78)
at org.eclipse.jpt.jaxb.core.schemagen.Main.execute(Main.java:64)
at org.eclipse.jpt.jaxb.core.schemagen.Main.main(Main.java:49)
```

Comment: Has nothing to do with `maven-jaxb2-plugin` or `jaxb2-basics`, I've removed the tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for the annotation like which has an enum array field like this:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface SomeAnnotation
{
    SomeEnum[] value();
}
```

The core problem is `EnumConstantNotPresentException`:

> Thrown when an application tries to access an enum constant by name and the enum type contains no constant with the specified name. This exception can be thrown by the API used to read annotations reflectively.

So most probably you have some enum in annotation somewhere which Eclipse code generator does not "have" in a sense that it is, for instance, not present in classpath when code generator is invoked or when the enum which is present in the classpath does not have the used enum value. This can be in case the code generator uses another version of the JAR containing the enum class and there was some difference.

To resolve the issue try to find the problematic annotation. If you can't find it using the "annotation that has an enum array" criteria, write a test which creates a `JAXBContext` for your classes and set a breakpoint at `sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseEnumArray`. This will be invoked on all the enum arrays so you'll get an idea what to look for. Comment out this annotations one by one to find what causes the problem.

Finally, general advice. Do not generate code from IDE. This is a build task, use a build management tool like Maven or Gradle for this.